# Flex 3: Which components to use to build a custom video bar (like Youtube player)?

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, video, actionscript, flex3

I need to develop a custom FLV video player with some features like Youtube's player: a "double" progress bar with loading and playing information, and the ability to click it to navigate the video.
Which components should I use to accomplish this?
Maybe 2 progress bars on top of each other? If so, then how can I click on it to navigate to a certain part of the video?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: If you really want to stick with Flex 3, you're in a world of pain. This is the kind of thing the Flex 4 (Spark) skinning architecture is perfect for.

Comment: RIAstar, unfortunately I am. Do you recommend any tutorial or guide? Even with Flex 4, shouldn't the components be the same?